# getline(cin.name) gets skipped

Tags: c++, function, input

I call a function from a function in C++ that has the line `getline(cin,name)` where name is a string. the first time through the loop, the program does not wait for input. It will on all other passes through the loop. Any ideas on why?

```
void getName (string& name)
{ 
     int nameLen; 
      do{
          cout << "Enter the last Name of the resident." << endl << endl
              << "There should not be any spaces and no more than 15"
              << " characters in the name."  << endl;



         getline(cin,name);
            cout << endl;
            nameLen = name.length();// set len to number of characters input

         cout << "last" << name << endl;
         }
      while (nameLen < LastNameLength);   
      return;
}
```

Comment: Maybe there is some data still waiting to be read from `stdin` before the function is called.

Comment: Please provide a *small, complete* program that demonstrates this problem. The problem you've described is probably caused by some code you didn't show us.

Comment: Off-topic: please don't use `endl` when you mean `'\n'`. `endl` flushes the output stream which is needlessly inefficient.

Comment: @Rob unless you're printing debug statements when there might be a crash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure there isn't left overs since the last time you read something from cin, like:
In an earlier point in your program:

```
int number;
cin >> number;
```

The input you give:

```
5
```

Later in the program:

```
getline(cin,name);
```

and `getline` will seem to not be called, but rather it collected the newline from the last time you took input because when you use `cin >>` it leaves new lines.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I added a line cin.ignore('\n') before the getline. There were cin statements in the previous function. This corrected the problem

Answer (score 2):

It may be because of the input stream. The getline function stops reading input after is receives the first newline char. If for example there are multiple newlines within the buffer of std::cin - the getline will return every time it encounters one.

Check the input you are expecting.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any:
**cin << variableName;**

lines of code? I ran into getline() skipping run-time errors when I was using:

**cin << intvariable** and **subsequently getline(cin, variable)**.

This is because the cin stream object holds a buffer of input. When you enter the newline character I assume it is trunacated from the stream going to the variable asisgnment, yet is still contained within the cin object instance itself.

One workaround I used is **cin.ignore()**; after the **cin << integer** statement.

Another user mentioned parsing all input from getline into integers, floats - not root beer -, and strings. Good luck and check your code for the dual use of cin & getline().